# How exactly does the HOST/machine SPN work?

Tags: iis, kerberos

Normally when you set up Kerberos for IIS, you would do something like `setspn -A HTTP/machine some_account`.  When IIS 7 is installed, it registers the SPN "HOST/machine" for its kernel-mode authentication.  Why does this work?  Is "HOST" some kind of catch-all SPN that matches when there is no protocol-specific (e.g. "HTTP") SPN registered?  Because the client will still specify the HTTP SPN in its TGT requests, right?

(Sorry if this is a simple question, "HOST" is a predictably difficult term to google)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HOST is a catch all for several SPNs.  These are determined by the field SPNmappings in CN=Directory Service,CN=Windows NT,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=MyDC,DC=com in your AD using ADSIEdit.msc

See this site for more information [The problem with duplicate SPNs – alternate working title… KB321044++](http://blog.joeware.net/2008/07/17/1407/)

And so I don't forget:

`CN=Directory Service,CN=Windows NT,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=contoso,DC=com`

Comment: Can you clarify one thing: it's legal and possible to have an SPN for one of the classes that defer to HOST registered to another account, right?

Comment: Well, no.  SPN's have to be unique. Period. So typically you see a web server with HTTP SPN's via HOST for the machine name, then an alias registered with the SPN HTTP/<alias>.  But if you were adding an SPN for a duplicate machine, that would be bad.